# Check if any date from given dates is located between multiple dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table like shown below, and i need to now if `u_id1` have any `from` value that is located between other `from` and `to` values

Query to see if any of this is true.

```
date3 < date1  < date4

date5 < date1 < date6

or

date1 < date3 < date2

date5 < date3 < date6

or

date1 < date5 < date2

date3 < date5 < date4


> u_id   from to

> u_id1  date1  date2

> u_id1  date3  date4

> u_id1  date5  date6
```

Comment: you can use self join. see http://www1.udel.edu/evelyn/SQL-Class3/SQL3_self.html

Answer (score 0):

```
select t0.u_id1, format('%s < %s < $s', t1.from, t0.from, t1.to)
from
    t t0
    inner join
    t t1 on t1.from < t0.from < t1.to
```

Comment: Please add some description too there.